# Tomcat 7 SSL and "Export to Excel"

Tags: excel, tomcat, ssl

As the old saying goes ... this will be my first attempt at posting a question to this forum. Please be kind with my feedback regarding my post. :-)

I recently found out that later versions of Internet Explorer have a feature to "Export to Excel". The end user simply executes a right mouse click on the page, selects "Export to Excel", and "automagically" the web page is imported into MS Excel. I say I recently found out because I spend most of my time in *nix environments and rarely have a need to use IE for anything other than accessing web pages at work.

Anyway, we recently configured one of our Apache Tomcat 7.x instances to use SSL to encrypt the transport layer. When the end user tried to use the "Export to Excel" feature in IE, the page could not be displayed in Excel. When SSL is disabled, the feature works.

I had a couple of ideas, based upon similar type situations happening in the past, but they were mostly code related (i.e. created an Excel file to push to the browser). But, after searching for a few hours, I did not find any references to the "Export to Excel" feature in IE.

I'm sure it's something simple, but all I need is a point in the right direction.

**Edit - Server.xml config**:

```
<Connector 
     port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
     SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
     clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
     keystoreFile="${catalina.home}\conf\ssl_keystore" keystorePass="changeit" />
```

Comment: Is your SSLConnector configured for clientAuth="true" in the server.xml? Do you need a client certificate installed in your browser to access the Https version?

Comment: Here's the Connector element in the server.xml file:
`
<Connector port="8443"
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="${catalina.home}\conf\ssl_keystore"
           keystorePass="changeit"
/>
`

Answer (score 0):

Compare the HTTP headers sent with and without SSL. IE has, in the past, exhibited odd behaviour when serving things like PDFs via SSL.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Turns out the customer doesn't see this issue as an issue. I also noticed that other applications in our shop do not allow for this IE feature to be used. I'm thinking that the browser session management isn't "transferred" (for lack of a better term) to Excel. In other words, if the application issues a session cookie to IE, that cookie cannot be read from Excel using the "Export to Excel" feature. I'd love it if I was wrong, but that's what seems to be going on.